# Firestore rules not working properly?! (documentId & get())

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I've been bashing my head against a wall all day trying to backpedal and debug my firestore rules. I have stripped it right back to where the issue is, which should hopefully make it easier to explain.

Everything works **if** if do this with my rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user_partnerships/{partnershipId} {
        allow read: if 0 == 0;
    }
  }
}
```

It returns 2 documents, with id's **cLMZw4EqkSLnafGt8wz7** and **ky4hxaEqI8BeLFoip2DF**, as expected.

By using the above and returning data, I know the query itself isn't the issue since the rule is allowing all data to be queried.

So moving on to the issue.. if I now change the above to the below, it stops working and says I don't have permission:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user_partnerships/{partnershipId} {
        allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_partnerships/$(partnershipId));
    }
  }
}
```

This surely doesn't make sense, since the current document being processed by the rule is what it's querying and obviously exists..

So it seems with this, the **{partnershipId}** parameter in the rule, which is the documentId, isn't being passed to the get() function, and isn't seemingly accessible at all.

I checked to see if I could simulate a working rule by just typing the id's I know exist into the get() functions, and it worked:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user_partnerships/{partnershipId} {
        allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_partnerships/ky4hxaEqI8BeLFoip2DF) || exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_partnerships/cLMZw4EqkSLnafGt8wz7);
    }
  }
}
```

This works! So it shows the passing of the **partnershipId** variable isn't working?

Now this isn't the kind of rules I intend on using, I intend on querying something using the **partnershipId** to gather role permissions, but since the **partnershipId** doesn't even seem to be accessible, I can't even begin that.

Please help? I can't seem to access the *match /user_partnerships/{partnershipId}* variable at all.

Edit: another example of this not making any sense:

**This works**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user_partnerships/{partnershipId} {
        allow read: if resource.data.permissionOwner == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

**But this doesn't???**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /user_partnerships/{partnershipId} {
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user_partnerships/$(partnershipId)).data.permissionOwner == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the actual queries that don't work the way you expect.  Security rules don't have much meaning without understanding what exactly the client code is doing, and what are the expected results.